# RubyMotion: how to display unicode character in Android?

Tags: android, ruby, rubymotion

How to display unicode character in `TextView` in Android using **RubyMotion**?

I tried

```
MainModule.get.setText('\u00d7')
MainModule.get.setText('0x00d7')
```

Where `get` is to get the `TextView` object.

But neither works, it still displays the original string(\u00d7 or 0x00d7).

---

Edit

I am using `Ruby` to write Android, not `Java`.

Comment: @1615903 I am using Ruby to write Android, not Java

Answer (score 0):

I get you a method that unicode to string, I hole that would be useful for you.

```
mTextView.setText(unicode2String("\\u00d7"));
...
public String unicode2String(String unicode) {
    StringBuffer string = new StringBuffer();
    String[] hex = unicode.split("\\\\u");
    for (int i = 1; i < hex.length; i++) {
        int data = Integer.parseInt(hex[i], 16);
        string.append((char) data);
    }
    return string.toString();
}
```

Comment: `RubyMotion` is using `Ruby` to write Android